# Update Dashboard Without Using Submit Button in Jasperserver

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

This is the case: I have a dashboard in my jasperserver, and I have a dropdown as an input control in it. What I must do if I want the dashboard to be auto-updated when I change the value in the dropdown, so I don't have to put a Submit button? (And not using auto-interval for the update)

I also have two reports inside the dashboard, but I want it to be updated separately, without causing other report to be reprocessed, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this ?